# FabricJS - lock height and resize only width?

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

I am using FabricJS and I want to let the user resize a shape only by its width, and hide or lock the height handles somehow so they wont be usable.

Does anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can lock height scaling like this: myObject.lockScalingY = true;

The height scaling handles will be visible, but not usable.